# LDO LP2992 5V Naming

Tags: ldo, 5v

Some one could explain to me please the difference between the LP2992IM5-5.0/NOPB, LP2992IM5X-5.0/NOPB, LP2992AIM5X-5.0, LP2992AIM5-5.0? They all seems to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [LP2992 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2992.pdf), you'll see that the "A" versions have tighter tolerance on their specifications.

The "I" seems to denote industrial temperature range, although they never explicitly say this. They don't seem to offer any other temperature range anyway.

"M5" denotes the SOT-23 package.

The "NOPB" notation means "no lead" (RoHS-compliant).

However, I can't figure out what the "X" denotes. I suspect it has something to do with how the part is delivered on different kinds of reels for high-volume manufacturing.

Comment: I think you're right about the "X". On p 14 of the datasheet you'll see the "X" indiates a package qty of 3000 pieces (in some cases, 4500 pieces), while without the "X" the qty is 1000.

Comment: is it ok if I connect the ON/OFF input of a 5V regulator in a 12V input right?

Comment: Yes, ON/OFF can be tied to Vin.

Comment: @DaveTweed thanks...but I will be changing the project..so I guess I will be using a MCP1703 5.0V instead...any advices? :D